# Not able to loading static files with express

Tags: node.js, express

Tried all possible combinations I can think of but not able to load static files using express server.
**Dir Structure**

```
app
--todoApp.html
----server.js //node file
----jquery.js
----backbone.js
```

**Node server**

```
var http = require('http'),
    express = require('express');

var app = express();
app.listen(3000);
app.set('views', __dirname);
app.use(express.static(__dirname));
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
console.log(__dirname);
app.get('/', function(req, res){
    //res.send('Whats up?');
    res.render('../todoApp.html');
});
```

`__dirname` prints as `app/js` ehich is correct. But page loads with error `the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)  http://localhost:3000/js/jquery.js`.

HTML loads the script like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/backbone.js"></script>
```

I tried multiple things but it does not work. 

Tried following:
`app.use('/js',express.static(__dirname));`
or 
`app.use('/',express.static(__dirname));`

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the current directory is already the `js` directory, you don't need to specify it in the `<script>` tags when loading your JavaScript  files:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="underscore-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="backbone.js"></script>
```

When you set a static directory in express, that directory effectively becomes the root, so all of your static file paths should be relative to that directory.

Also, it is probably not a good idea to have your server-side code in a static directory, since this would allow anyone using your server access to your server side code. It would be better to put all of your static files in a different directory, and set that as the static directory in express.